# How to start an Activity from one android device to an other?

Tags: android

I am creating an app for a taxi company.I want the client calls the free cab that is near to him.So I thought  the clients device sent "something" to drivers device in which an new activity with clients information starts.Both devicies run the same app!I need help to know what that "something" can be!I dont want to be a call or a sms because of charge!Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go with, Push Notification concepts it may help you, for more go through this link http://urbanairship.com/

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to use something like [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) to send a notification to the other device so that it knows to start the activity